# Symfony2 + swift mailer + command : email body displayed into the console

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have created **a new command** into my Symfony app.

In this command I call to a service which **send email** *as mailer from FOS bundle*.

My problem is that the **email body is displayed** into the console in order to send the email.

I want to say that the `msg mailer` method **works fine out of** the command.

**Here my command**:

```
class ReminderCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();            

        # the mailer service works fine out the command
        $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
        $mailer->sendMsg(...);          


        $text = ' => mail sent';

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

Please help

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 16):

I think you may have used the memory spooling.

When using memory spooling, you must be aware that because of how symfony handles console commands, emails are not sent automatically. You must take care of flushing the queue yourself. Use the following code to send emails inside your console command:

```
$container = $this->getContainer();
$mailer = $container->get('mailer');
$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

Refrence:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

Comment: Yes that's it! If you send emails with same configuration over commandline it's only possible to to flush the email queue manually. Thx for the info! +1

Answer (score -2):

I have found the solution.

Use the service this way:

```
    $this->container->get('mailer')->sendMsg(...)
```

not

```
    # the mailer service works fine out the command
    $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
    $mailer->sendMsg(...);
```

It works now

Have fun and hope it helps some guys

Sam